# How to insert space between inline nodes (side by side)?

Tags: xml, xslt

My problem is easy as pie.
I use php to apply stylesheet to XMLDocument.

I have some XML elements like this :

```
<a>
  Lorem
  <b>ipsum</b>
  <c>dolor<d>sit amet</d></c>
</a>
```

Problem exists between `dolor` and `sit amet`.
I would like to know the easiest way to print `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` with blank spaces between each text nodes.

I use this part of stylesheet:

```
[...]
<xsl:value-of select="a/descendant-or-self::*" />
[...]
```

But the result is `Lorem ipsum dolorsit amet`

I also tried `a/descendant-or-self::*`, `a/descendant-or-self::*/text()` with template matching text(), `concat(' ', a/descendant-or-self::*)`.

I don't know the names of sub elements, that's why I use `descendant-or-self::*`

How to print these sub elements as text, with correct words spacing ?

Comment: Did you remove the PHP tag?

Comment: Ho yes sorry :S because it was a little confusing. The solution must be an xslt solution. Thanks for your reactivity and your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is that you need to output the text nodes only, discarding the elements, while keeping the words separated by spaces. If so, you could try this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="out">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($out)"/>      
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*[node()]">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',normalize-space(.))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This sheet simply descends recursively to any nodes, discards the elements, extracts the texts and prefixes them with a single space. The `normalize-space` function replaces sequences of one-or-more whitespace with a single space.

Comment: It's ok with a little adaptation to my xml structure, it works fine. I validate your answer. I think it's the easiest way with xslt. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace to add a space after each opening tag.

```
Echo preg_replace("/(<\w+>)/", "$1 ", $s);
```

Output:

```
<a> 
  Lorem
  <b> ipsum</b>
  <c> dolor<d> sit amet</d></c>
</a>
```

https://3v4l.org/rh1TP

Comment: It could be a good option to insert spaces between words definitively in xml document.